# How do I create a comma-separated list of values in Google Sheets

Tags: list, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How do I create a comma-separated list of values which pulls the top value from each list using a common value in Google sheets. For example, if I have three lists and want to use a common value to pull the value of the top list into a comma-separated list (hope that makes sense):

**Category 1**

apples

oranges

pears

**Category 2**

apples

pears

grapes

**Category 3**

oranges

apples

celery

*I'm trying to create lists that look like the following using the common value (oranges, apples, etc):*

oranges: category 3, category 1

apples: category 1, category 2, category 3

celery: category 3

pears: category 1, category 2

grapes: category 1

So many thanks if someone could help me with this!

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear? Are these lists columns in a sheet?

Comment: Yes. They are in one sheet together. I'm looking for a formula. Sorry... obviously this isn't my area of expertise ;)

Comment: Have you considered using VLOOKUP() https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en?

Comment: Yes! But I not quite sure what that would look like cause I need the final as a comma-separated list

Answer (score 1):

If ColA - ColC has the following:

> Category 1    Category 2  Category 3
>
> apples    apples  oranges
>
> oranges   pears   apples
>
> pears grapes  celery

Put the following formula in, say, E1:

```
={"Values";UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE({TRANSPOSE($A$2:$A$4),TRANSPOSE($B$2:$B$4),TRANSPOSE($C$2:$C$4)}))}
```

This will create an array with a header and transposes the unique values from the 3 ranges of categories (from rows 2 to 4, change if needed). This way each value is extracted but there are no repeats.

Then, put header text in F1 ("Categories"). Put this formula in F2 and drag down to match each result in ColE:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,{{IFERROR(IF(SEARCH($E2,join("",$A$2:$A)),$A$1,""))},{IFERROR(IF(SEARCH($E2,join("",$B$2:$B)),$B$1,""),)},{IFERROR(IF(SEARCH($E2,join("",$C$2:$C)),$C$1,""),)}})
```

This formula will search each category in ColA - ColC for the unique fruit in ColE. If there's a match, it will return the Category. The Textjoin() function separates the results with a comma.

[image]

Comment: OMG! You are amazing! Thank you so much. This totally works! I just want to let you know what this means... I used to be in extreme chronic pain and doctors were clueless. I healed using fruits/veggies medicinally. Now I coach other women who struggle through the same type of debilitating pain. They are usually told it's incurable. This formula helps me personalize each plan and bring their pain down effeciently. It really does work and I've witness their pain reduce and heal like mine did. I just wanted you to know what you have helped. Many thanks from all of us!

Comment: Glad to help! Best of luck in your endeavors. 